# What is this certificate I found on my computer and can I delete it?

Tags: certificates

I noticed an error in my event viewer logs about certificate with specific thumbprint unable to be renewed. After I dug some more, I found that the certificate in question was accompanied by two other certificates located in Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder in Local Computer certificates. These certificates were still valid and are named: XBL client IPsec issuing CA and XBL server IPsec issuing CA

I tried googling these certificates but I found no concrete answers as to what they're used for. Best result I found is that they're related to Xbox live. The strange thing, however, is that I'm using two other computers and the other ones do not have these certificates installed even though they're all using the same Windows 10 version and all of them having the default xbox apps still installed.

Does anyone have any idea what these certificates are? If I cannot be sure what they're used for, and seemingly they are not needed, could I just safely delete them?

Answer (score 1):

Those certificates might have been installed with a game on your computer. They are used to authenticate communications with Microsoft servers.

You can uninstall them, but the online functionality of some of your game might stop working. In this case, reinstalling those games should reinstall those certificates and restore the functionality.